# Computing the integral $\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ ....

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

> Prove that $$\large\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}-\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigg)dx=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(-\ln(n) + \sum \limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k}\Bigg)$$

I was reading an article on Euler–Mascheroni constant$\Big(\gamma\approx0.577215664901532\Big)$, when I read that it is defined as the limiting difference between the harmonic series and the natural logarithm :

$$\gamma=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(-\ln(n) + \sum \limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k}\Bigg)$$

That is completely fine, but in the next "step" this limit is equated to a definite integral of reciprocal of $x$ subtracted from the reciprocal of floor of $x$.

It can not really understand this transition from limit to a definite integral. Also, I could not find even a single proof of this equivalence anywhere. A geometrical explanation (or even an algebraic one) will surely help me understand this.

Thanks in Advance ! :-)

Comment: Riemann sums seem to be the most direct way

Comment: Well the integral from 1 to n of 1/x is ln(n) and the integral from 1 to n of 1/floor(x) is the n^th harmonic number. So the equality should hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an improper integral, so just write it as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n{1\over \lfloor x\rfloor}-{1\over x}\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}-\log n\right)$$

The first term by noting that $[x]^{-1} = k^{-1}$ on $[k, k+1)$ and the second by one of the (many) definitions for $\log x$.

Comment: Oh!!! So Simple!!! I was thinking that limits must be involved as it an improper integral but it just did not come to my mind that I can integrate term-wise. So Silly of me !!! Anyways, thanks a lot for answering my question. :-)